# Check if connected to geodatabase as database owner (DBO) with ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, enterprise-geodatabase, sql-server

I was wondering if anyone knows of a reasonable workflow with ArcPy, for ArcGIS Pro/Python3 (or ArcMap 10.8.1/Python2.7, but I'd prefer a solution for Pro), to check if a given *.SDE connection file connects as the database owner for a given feature class.  This is for MS SQL Server, using the DBO model, so checking the user-name from the connection (available via `arcpy.Describe`) isn't necessarily enough.

If it helps, I'm trying to write some tools to delete all the features from a number of feature classes before some new data gets appended in.  The Truncate geoprocessing tool works a lot more efficiently for large datasets, so I'd like to use that whenever possible. However, it can only be run on non-versioned data by the data owner (for enterprise geodatabases).  I can get if it's versioned via `arcpy.Describe`, but I need a way to check if the connection is data owner so I can know if Truncate will work or not or if I'd have to resort to using the Delete Features tool.

I know I could also put the Truncate tool in a try block and catch geoprocessing exceptions and run the Delete Features in the except block, but that seems even less efficient as it still seems to take some time to spin up the Truncate tool far enough to get the error message.

Comment: Can't you just use a Windows call to check if the user has admin rights?  Short of creating a random table with a CREATE TABLE statement (via `arcpy,ArcSDESQLExecute()`) then querying the catalog to see the owning schema, there is no way to do this.

Comment: @Vince, I was hoping there was something in arcpy.Describe or some other hidden arcpy feature or ESRI script I had missed that would provide an easy/efficient way to do this.  I'll have to check if there's a good way in SQL to identify if a connected user is DBO, thanks for the suggestion (I normally work via the ESRI tools, so not as familiar with the straight SQL route to get there).

Comment: No, no hidden magic in the Esri toolbox.  You might be able to do something in SQL as a view, but that's really a topic for [dba.se].